# Can I use PushKit for standard push notification with out using VoIP? and what are the chances that app get rejected in review?

Tags: push-notification, voip, pushkit

I want to do some task without using VOIP functionalities when received push notification and app is force quitted and then relaunch  app in background, So what are the chances to reject app by apple.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, looks like you want to use Pushkit, even though your app is non-voip.

If that's the case, Very high Chances that your app will be rejected during App Review !